# Mock dependency in Elm

Tags: ajax, unit-testing, elm

In every `elm` file, dependencies to be imported are declared at the top.
Is there a way, while testing the application, to mock a dependency?

For example, suppose I have an application using the HTTP module to make an ajax request. When I test my module, I would like to avoid to make the actual ajax request, but I'd like to have a mocked HTTP module which will return a fake response just for the sake of testing.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Elm is a pure functional language, you often don't need to do any kind of mocking because side effects are limited to interaction with ports. Most of the time, you can just call the function you want to test directly.

Consider this typical example of an HTTP request task being mapped to an Action:

```elm
type alias MyThing =
  { id : Int
  , name : String
  }

type Action
  = FetchData
  | ErrorOccurred String
  | DataFetched MyThing

myDecoder : Json.Decoder MyThing
myDecoder =
  Json.object2
    MyThing
    ("id" := Json.int) 
    ("name" := Json.string) 

fetchData : Effects Action
fetchData =
  Http.get myDecoder url
    |> Task.toResult
    |> Task.map httpResultToAction
    |> Effects.task

httpResultToAction : Result Http.Error MyThing -> Action
httpResultToAction result =
  case result of
    Ok thing ->
      DataFetched thing
    Err err ->
      ErrorOccurred (toString err)
```

There are a few things that would benefit from testing here, but none of them require mocking.

You may want to test the JSON decoding of `myDecoder`. You could simply create some good and bad JSON strings and use [`Json.Decode.decodeString`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/latest/Json-Decode#decodeString) with `myDecoder` to test that the end result meets your expectation.

The thing that is probably most in need of unit testing is the `httpResultToAction` function. Again, in this example, this requires no mocking. All you need to do is create a number of good and bad `Result` values and test your expectations.

Comment: Would there be a way to test `fetchData` in this situation ?

Comment: It depends on what you actually want to test. `fetchData` returns an `Effects` type, which is a shallow wrapper around a `Task`. It doesn't actually perform an HTTP request. Your tests would revolve around peeling apart the resulting `Effects` return value and inspecting the `Task`, but at that point your tests seem more focused on testing core Elm code than actually testing your application.

Comment: Actually, what I could find tricky to get right at first is the chaining of `|>` operators. But then, maybe simply getting it to compile is proof enough that it works ; and testing the other parts is where the value lies.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that your answer is only relevant for unit testing.  If the OP is trying to do BDD or some other kind of acceptance testing, it may be very relevant and beneficial to mock API responses.  I haven't come across a great way to do this within elm tests, but am attempting to use WebdriverIO and Mocha with the node package `mock-api-server` to mock responses.

Answer (score 1):

You should separate the code that calls into the Http module from the real logic you want to test.

For example, if you write a function that takes a `Result Error String` as an argument (such as might come back from a call to `Http.getString`) you can easily unit test that function without needing to make a real HTTP call.