# Unit Testing Tasks in Elm

Tags: elm

I'm building an app that will use some tasks as defined by the elm in the elm architecture.

Is there a way to unit tests these tasks independently without having to test the whole application?

I'm already using the **elm-community/elm-test** package for unit testing the functions but but how do I go for testing tasks now. How can these tasks be executed and the response awaited for and then be compared to some expected value?

Comment: See [this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35134676/mock-dependency-in-elm) which outlines why you don't need to test the framework, but only your pure Elm code. Does that help?

Comment: you might want to take a look at https://github.com/avh4/elm-testable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple program that walks down a list of commands (wrapping tasks) and expected resulting messages, checking the actual received messages against what is expected. The `init` function sends out the first command in the list and the `update` function verifies the next message received and then sends out the command for the next test.

See, for example, https://github.com/fredcy/localstorage/blob/master/test/Test2.elm

Comment: Thanks, I eventually coded a few days ago some tests suites in the manner that you are describing. It's a fare enough solution. Thanks for answering. By the way, thanks again for the localstorage library, I had a look at it a few days ago.